# Cannot embed App Maker app in iframe on external website

Tags: iframe, google-app-maker

I have created deployment for App Maker app, with URL https://script.google.com/a/macros/domain.com/s/AKfy..adwq/exec

Also enabled "Allow app to be embedded in any site within an iFrame" option in App Settings.

But when inserting on website:

```
<iframe src="https://script.google.com/a/macros/domain.com/s/AKfy..adwq/exec"></iframe>
```

app is not displayed, and this error is in dev console:

> Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/a/domain.com/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https://script.google.com/a/macros/domain.com/s/AKfy../exec&followup=https://script.google.com/a/macros/domain.com/s/AKfy../exec' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

As I understand, because App Maker app requires GSuite account to run, it redirects to different Google's authorization URL first.

But I don't understand why this URL is banned from displaying in `iframe`, and how it is possible to embed App Maker app then?

Comment: If you've logged in before visiting the site, Does it still redirect?

Comment: @TheMaster yes, iframe redirects even if logged in to app in regular tab.

Comment: Reported issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131114385 but looking for some workaround

Comment: Are third party cookies enabled?

Comment: @TheMaster found out that Ghostery extension was blocking third-party cookies, thanks for pointing

Comment: You said it's fixed in issuetracker. So, now it doesn't ask for login credentials again? Or does it display login form in a iframe

Comment: @TheMaster first